# How to find keywords in HTML code?

Tags: html, keywords, meta-keywords

I want to check if on a web page I can find defined words. For example I want to check if a web page contains word 'abc'.
I know that some pages contains `meta tag` with `name = keywords` and `name=description`.
But now every page contains this tag. So I'm also searching in `<p>` tags. But where else I should search for a matching words to determine the topic of the page?

Comment: Are these sites you control? Are you wanting to do this yourself - programmatically? Or use a third party tool? "where else I should search" - all page _content_. (?)

Comment: @w3d I use python to open the url and read the content. I was thinking about all page content, but maaybe I should focuse on special tags and then I don't need to search throw all page conent?

Comment: If you just need to determine the "topic" of the page then you might be able to get enough information from the `title`, `h1`, `h2`, etc. elements - providing the document is "well formed"? However, if you want to "check if a web page contains word" (as you state in the first part of your question) then I can see how you would do that without searching _everything_?

Comment: I think your question is not precise enough. It's hard to give an answer to this as it stands now.

Comment: Can I ask if this is part of your keyword research or just a general question? There is a difference.

Comment: @closetnoc I want to check if a webpage corresponds to the set theme, like for example: 'dogs'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things you can do. You can `view page source` code and look for the following:

- `title` tag
- `description` meta-tag
- `h1`, `h2`, `h3`... tags
- first 1 or 2 paragraphs

You will want to discount any stop words of common words of course. While the description meta-tag has little or no value for SEO, it does offer great clues to keywords and page topic. You can always create a spread-sheet to keep track of pages and keywords of course.

Another option, and one that I prefer, is to use a keyword density analyzer. Keyword density for SEO is largely a myth, however, these tools offer great clues to the hidden potential of any page and clearly pin-points the topic keywords that any page will perform well for. This may be the best option for you.

My favorite now requires an account: http://www.ranks.nl/ This may be a good idea if you are going to use a tool often. Today, I recommend: http://tools.seobook.com/general/keyword-density/ This is a free tool and not quite as detailed as ranks.nl but may be good enough for your purposes. I use both from time to time to check that I am on track when I write a new page.

Another option is to use an SEO analysis tool. I like best for this: SEO PowerSuite from http://www.link-assistant.com/ This is an expensive option and I only recommend this if you need to use the tool a lot for competitive analysis or checking your own work on a larger site.

If this is too much for you, then perhaps Screaming Frog can help: http://www.screamingfrog.co.uk/seo-spider/ It can be free up to a limit (500 pages), then you have to purchase a license. People seem to like this tool and I have tried it. It requires the option to spider your site directly. I suspect you can target single pages too. Please note, there are more features than listed on this initial page so dig deeper if this looks like a good option for you. I can recommend this tool from my experience.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for keywords which are used on someone else's site, I suggest looking at ALT tags and possible TITLES on images. Also a good idea to look at

tags.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to determine the content title by just looking at the browser window's tab title or you can use a third party tool like [Seositecheckup](http://seositecheckup.com/) to determine the content of that particular page automatically.